# Multidimensional array unique based on value (not array key)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which I need to be sorted with uniqueness as I have duplicated records, so I need `array_unique` to go through the array and remove duplicates by the value, e.g.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 324
            [time_start] => 1301612580
            [level] => 0.002
            [input_level] => 0.002
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 325
            [time_start] => 1301612580
            [level] => 0.002
            [input_level] => 0.002
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 326
            [time_start] => 1301612580
            [level] => 0.002
            [input_level] => 0.002
        )
)
```

There are duplicated `time_start`, which they are all the same, also `level` and `input_level` but they are not to be affected, only if there are matching `time_start` it should remove it and process the whole array *(the array is bigger than you think, but I just posted a small example of the array)*. Should remove dupes and return like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 324
            [time_start] => 1301612580
            [level] => 0.002
            [input_level] => 0.002
        )
)
```

Questions I've found that didn't work:

- [reformat multidimensional array based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405547/reformat-multidimensional-array-based-on-value)
- [Delete element from multidimensional-array based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466159/delete-element-from-multidimensional-array-based-on-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$input = array( /* your data */ );
$temp  = array();
$keys  = array();

foreach ( $input as $key => $data ) {
    unset($data['id']);
    if ( !in_array($data, $temp) ) {
        $temp[]     = $data;
        $keys[$key] = true;
    }
}

$output = array_intersect_key($input, $keys);
```

or

```
$input = array( /* your data */ );
$temp  = $input;

foreach ( $temp as &$data ) {
    unset($data['id']);
}

$output = array_intersect_key($input, array_unique($temp));
```

Comment: Your keys are going to wind up being the array indexes, not the individual associative field names.

Comment: I think the op only cares about a single field, not 'everything except id'.  Also... not to cast dispersions here... but does array_unique work that way?  I thought it basically used a strict equality internally, which would preclude its usage for comparing arrays of this nature.

Comment: Ok, I looked it up.  It appears to use string equality for checking.  Which doesn't quite make sense in this context, until I read this:  
Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.  --  This is an array of associative arrays.

Any which way, the use of array_unique scares me.  : )

Comment: Ok good. It works, but the array keys are not indexed properly which I need to use the array in a `for` loop, the keys are skipped like `[0], [12], [18]` etc.

Comment: Because of it got the unique arrays by their keys. If you want to renumerate the array just use: `$output = array_values($output)`

Answer (score 6):

```
$temp = array();
array_filter($yourArray, function ($v) use (&$temp) {
    if (in_array($v['time_start'], $temp)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        array_push($temp, $v['time_start']);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Uses [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) which will filter an array based on the result of a callback (I used an anonymous function which can be used since PHP 5.3). The `time_start` values are collected into a temporary array.

Comment: One thing to corrent. *array_filter* returns filtered array and doesn't change array at place (by refference). More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll just have to walk it:

```
$usedVals = array();
$outArray = array();
foreach ($targetArray as $arrayItem)
{
    if (!in_array($arrayItem['time_start'],$usedVals))
    {
        $outArray[] = $arrayItem;
        $usedVals[] = $arrayItem['time_start'];
    }
}
return $outArray;
```

Comment: @Darzan As opposed to what?  : )  It'll eat more memory than say, the suggestion above... but it really shouldn't be much slower.  Plus, there are some logic flaws there that I was about to address.

Answer (score 0):

```
$uniq = array();
foreach($no_unique as $k=>$v) if(!isset($uniq[$v['time_start']])) $uniq[$v['time_start']] = $v;
$uniq = array_values($uniq);
```